# Can we add a new shipping address in Apple Pay

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, stripe-payments, applepay

I have already in my application user has added **"Shipping Address"** I want to assign that address as `shippingAddress` `shippingContact` while user pay with `Apple Pay`.

> I have tried with below code "shippinAddress" is my dictionary which
>   has already a address that I want to use as Apple Pay Shipping
>   address.

```
PKPaymentRequest *paymentRequest = [Stripe paymentRequestWithMerchantIdentifier:merchantId];
paymentRequest.shippingContact = [self getShippingAddress_ApplePay];

-(PKContact*)getShippingAddress_ApplePay
{

PKContact *address = [[PKContact alloc] init];

NSPersonNameComponents *personName = [[NSPersonNameComponents alloc] init];
personName.givenName = [shippinAddress valueForKey:@"firstname"];
personName.familyName = [shippinAddress valueForKey:@"lastname"];


CNMutablePostalAddress * postalAddress = [[CNMutablePostalAddress alloc] init];
postalAddress.street = [shippinAddress valueForKey:@"street"];
postalAddress.city = [shippinAddress valueForKey:@"city"];
postalAddress.state = [shippinAddress valueForKey:@"region"];
postalAddress.postalCode = [shippinAddress valueForKey:@"postcode"];
postalAddress.ISOCountryCode = [shippinAddress valueForKey:@"country_id"];

CNPhoneNumber *phone = [[CNPhoneNumber alloc] initWithStringValue:[shippinAddress valueForKey:@"telephone"]];

address.name = personName;
address.emailAddress = [KCustomerInfo valueForKey:@"email"];
address.postalAddress = postalAddress;
address.phoneNumber = phone;

return address;

}
```

I am not getting this address while `paymentAuthorizationViewController` presents.

I have tried with set this too `paymentRequest.requiredShippingAddressFields = PKAddressFieldAll;`

Can anyone suggest, we can assign this way or not I yes then am I wrong with the way I have used?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no way to get the address as long as the `PKPaymentAuthorizationController` will be presented.
You need to wait for the delegate callback:

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                       didAuthorizePayment:(PKPayment *)payment
                                completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus))completion
```

As you may know, you can extract the address Information from the `PKPayment` object.

There are also callbacks which will be triggered if the user selected an address inside the `PKPaymentAuthorizationController` :

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                   didSelectShippingMethod:(PKShippingMethod *)shippingMethod
                                completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus status, NSArray<PKPaymentSummaryItem *> *summaryItems))completion;
```

or

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                  didSelectShippingContact:(PKContact *)contact
                                completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus status, NSArray<PKShippingMethod *> *shippingMethods,
                                                     NSArray<PKPaymentSummaryItem *> *summaryItems))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
```

**UPDATE**
Okay, it seems that i misunderstood the question.
To pass an address to the PKAuthController, you need to store that address inside the corresponding Address-Book Contact.

Comment: @Hi.. thanks for answer, Actually what I want is I have address is outside Apple Pay like in my one controller I already asked user for address and now I want to use that address as Shipping Address in Apple Pay. So can I assign that address or there is only way is we can add address through Authorization Controller?

Comment: The PKPaymentAuthController is using the stored Contact from the Address book. One thing you could do is to store the address inside the corresponding user contact, then it will appear automatically inside the PKAuthController i think .. should be worth a try. Would be interesting to know.

Comment: hmm ok let me check then that way